# Databricks: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.5 support will be dropped in the next release of cryptography

Tags: python, apache-spark, databricks

I'm using Databricks cluster 5.5 LTS version. And initially, I was using it with Python 2. But now I've upgraded from Python 2 to 3 keeping the cluster version the same. I've installed the library PGPy to perform the decryption of PGP files in python. However, due to this upgrade a scala notebook (which was running perfectly fine before this upgrade) is failing with the following error:

```
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 7, 10.139.64.4, executor 2): org.apache.spark.SparkException: Process List(/databricks/python/bin/pip, install, xlrd, --disable-pip-version-check) exited with code 1. /databricks/python3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/OpenSSL/_util.py:6: CryptographyDeprecationWarning: Python 3.5 support will be dropped in the next release of cryptography. Please upgrade your Python.
```

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: You updated from the out of date Python 2.7 to the out of date Python version 3.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple options:

- Turn off warnings (multiple ways to do this)

```py
import warnings
# Ignores only DeprecationWarningS (not recommended)
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', category=DeprecationWarning)
```

```sh
# Ignores all WarningS (not recommended, worse than above)
export PYTHONWARNINGS='ignore'
```

- Upgrade Python 3.5 (preferred)
- Revert PGPy to a previous version which still supports Python 3.5

Ultimately, you *will* end up upgrading Python to a supported version, and really, Python 3.5 is considered out of date; there are significant changes between it and 3.6 even. Also, it's important to do so since this involves OpenSSL. It's unwise to let that get out of date.

Take a look at the `warnings` module [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html) for more info on suppressing them.